# Null values for integers are not displayed properly by the Telerik NumericUpDown control

Tags: wpf, telerik, numericupdown

We are using the Telerik RadNumericUpDown control (2013 version) in our application to display & edit both double values and integers; 
   The control works fine for nullable double types: it displays nothing for a null value, and 0.00 for the 0 value. 
   We want the same behaviour for integers, but the control always displays 0 for null values.
   I've tried setting the NullValue to an empty string & null, based on the discussion here: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/numericupdown/null.aspx,
           but this doesn't solve our issue.

The XAML:

```
      <telerik:RadNumericUpDown Value="{Binding Path=Contents, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        NumberDecimalDigits="0"
                        IsEnabled="True"
                        IsEditable="True"
                        IsInteger="True"
                        NullValue=""                                
                        MinWidth="70"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
```

The Contents property is a nullable int.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding to the binding TargetNullValue='', worked for me

```
    <telerik:RadNumericUpDown Value="{Binding Path=Contents, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue=''}" 
                    IsEnabled="True"
                    IsEditable="True"
                    IsInteger="True"
                    NullValue=""                                
                    MinWidth="70"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
```

Comment: You saved me! The only answer I found that works. The key for me was to set that part of the binding expression.

Comment: I was prepared for having another run of tweaking and adjusting a Telerik control for WPF UI to fit my application's needs. But your elegant solution saved me wasting time barking up an unecessary tree. Thanks.